# Redirect to subdomain using web.config rules

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config

we migrate our webapp hosted in a directory "webapp" inside main domain:

```
http://www.example.com/webapp/
```

To the new subdomain without "webapp" folder:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/
```

I need to redirect only subdir "webapp". I don't want to redirect other url like `http://www.example.com/`, `http://www.example.com/folder1`, `http://www.example.com/folder2`, ....

But we have already sent a lot of emails to customers with link inside like: `<a href="http://www.example.com/webapp/login">LOGIN TO YOUR DASHBOARD</a>` or other link like `<a href="http://www.example.com/webapp/data/download.php/id=xxx">DOWNLOAD YOUR DOC</a>`

Now i'm trying to do a redirect trough web.config but it seem that nothing work.

If I try no navigate to, for example, `http://www.example.com/webapp/login` i don't get redirected to `http://subdomain.example.com/login/` as expected.

If I try no navigate to, for example, `http://www.example.com/webapp/data/download.php/id=43` i don't get redirected to `http://subdomain.example.com/data/download.php/id=43` as expected.

Any suggest?

```
<rule name="redirect-to-subdomain" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^webapp/$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://subdomain.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You rule won't work except for http://www.example.com/webapp/.

If you want to redirect link like http://www.example.com/webapp/login. Please try this rule.

```
<rule name="redirect-to-subdomain" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^webapp/(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://subdomain.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```